# ExtJS.Grid editing with lookup table

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, datagrid, crud

I'm developing a "simple" CRUD with ExtJS.Grid. This grid will refere to a DB table. I'm using [this example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#cell-editing) as basis.

But I can't figure out how to implement the "Light" column lookup. In the table to be edited, it's an int FK refering to another table, where the text is stored.

I don't need to edit the lookup table. What I need to do is query it (I could provide its data as a static JSON, no need to AJAX query it) so that the main table's FK is replaced by the text.

The editing row must show it as a select/dropdown (as in the example). And when user sends a Create/Update operation, it must send the chose item's ID so I can write it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible approaches:

1. column with combo editor would link to foreign id via dataIndex. This approach is very simple provided that you can load the complete combo store, i.e. it is not too many records. Also, you must ensure that the store is loaded early enough and to provide a column renderer that would display texts, not ids.
2. if you need a remote store for combo then another approach is better. You deliver from the server both FK (numeric id) and the corresponding text for each grid record, you link combo to the text, not to the id, and you provide `edit` event listener that updates both id and text when users selects from the combo. This approach is described in details together with the code in [Remote Combo in ExtJS Grid Example](http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#combo-in-grid)